# Conditional Fields is not working

Tags: views, commerce, entities

I m using [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) for Drupal 7 to create country state relational dropdown in my [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, but it is not working properly.

I created Country **US** and **Canada** and, depending upon those, **US States** and **Canadian States**; I created the relation, but in the front end all the drop-downs are shown.

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong? If this module does not work, how do I create a country state relational dropdown in my **Field Collection**?

Comment: Check with [Field Conditional State](https://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state) module. Recent version of this module is [here](https://drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state). Maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: Is that less buggy than the conditional fields module?

Comment: @RajeevK when I use the "Field Conditional States" module as per your suggestion but in this case "manage dependencies" tab is not appearing at all

Answer (score 1):

The other option to try is a custom form alter and add the [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) key to those fields. This is a code only, no ui approach, but it should work just as well for what you are looking to accomplish.

Here is an article that describes how to use #states. http://randyfay.com/states

Answer (score 0):

You can try the patch [Here](https://drupal.org/comment/8419673#comment-8419673) to enable field collection work with conditional fields. Optionally, instead of the field collection module, you can use the [Fieldgroup](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module with conditional fields and apply [This Fix](https://drupal.org/comment/8440137#comment-8440137), that personally worked for me.

Alternatively, you can use [Hierarchial Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) to create relational dropdown (i have suggested this module because you mentioned country and state relationships). Hierrachial select however doesnt work well with views exposed filters, but there is a suggested workaround in [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1758844)

There is also [Simple Hierarchial Select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) which works for nodes and views exposed filters